# Android keeps deleting my files while in recovery

Tags: android

I am trying to install a custom ROM on my HTC one m8. I unlocked the boot-loader, installed a custom recovery and everything works fine but whenever I try to put a custom ROM .zip on my SDcard, I see it with File Manager on my phone but if I reboot it on recover mode these files get deleted. I don't understand, help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved : sd card is too old and I can't write nor delete anything on it, I used adb push to put custom rom in the phone's internal memory